# How to interpret a conjunction as a loop condition?

Tags: while-loop, logic

I have a loop that doesn't exit and I need help converting a problem statement into a loop statement. Problem statement attached here: [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num,last,newnum;
    printf("ENTER YOUR NUMBER: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while (num != 7 || num != -7 || num != 0){
        last = num % 10;
        last = last * 2;
        num = num / 10;
        num = num - last;
        printf("%d",num);
    }
}
```

Comment: For `num == 7`, is the `while` condition true or false, and why?

Comment: A classic case of using boolean OR instead of boolean AND

Comment: I have edited  the picture for the question regarding the code and the condition is false

Comment: @UnholySheep I have used the && statement as well still getting the same error

Comment: [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Learn them.

Comment: "same error" What error? Also please do not upload images of text. Text is text, so post text as text, not as an image.

Comment: code is running till infinity while using or statement and and statement as well

Comment: You're using `||` in your `while` test.  Change it to `&&`.  With `||`, the condition can *never* be false.  It's basically a typo.

Comment: @TomKarzes There is more than one problem in this code. Beware of knee-jerk closing.

Comment: There is a problem with your assignment. The algorithm as stated will terminate if and only if the number *is* divisible by 7, so it is useless for checking divisibility by 7. However it can be fixed. Just run a couple dozens of tests and look at the output. Your new algorithm should be like that: if the new number is 0, 7, or -7, then the original number is divisible by 7; if the new number is (... fill this in ...), then the original number is *not* divisible by 7; otherwise, keep going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `||` operator when the `&&`  operator is the intended one. Let's look at why:
Say `num == 0`, then the loop should not execute but instead becomes an infinite loop.
If we solve the boolean condition like so:
`true || true || false` evaluates to `true`. The only case where it would evaluate to `false` would be if `num` equalled 7, -7, and 0 simultaneously, which is impossible. Plugging a sample value into the boolean condition is a good tool for figuring out why your loop ends too early or goes on too long.

```
while (num != 7 && num != -7 && num != 0)
```

This ^ is what your loop should be. However, as I was testing it, it seemed to get stuck in infinite loops regardless. That is because the loop body won't always result in 7, -7, or 0, as not every number is divisible by 7. The number 499443, divisible by 7, didn't produce an infinite loop, but the number 2, which is not, did.

Also, indent your code in the future, as it can make debugging easier.

If you need a more practical way to check if a number is divisible by 7, then you can use:

```
if (num % 7 == 0) {
    // Divisible by 7
}
```

Comment: Thanks man understood this was my first time posting on stack overflow that's why didn't knew how to properly post the code here although thanks for the answer